# Close 2 modal and open 1 again

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

In fancybox i'm open 2 modals of plugin and need close 2 and 1...

**Example: close 2 modal and open 1 modal again...
http://jsfiddle.net/g3R75/1/**

im using this but dont work:

```
afterClose: function() {

    $("a#button2").fancybox({
    'closeBtn' : false,
    'hideOnContentClick': true,
    'padding' : 0,
    'fitToView' : false,
    'helpers' : {  overlay : { css : { 'background' : 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)'  } }, buttons   : {} }
    }).trigger('click');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you may only need a single script for both modal boxes by adding a common selector to both links, the one outside and the one inside fancyBox (hidden content) so :

```
<a class="fancybox" id="button2" href="#parceiros"><div id="botao2" class="preto">PARCEIROS</div></a>

<div style="display:none">
    <div id="parceiros"> 
        <a class="fancybox" id="fancybox-button3" href="#parcas">Teste</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Notice** I added the *class* `fancybox` to both anchors and **kept** their current IDs. Then bind both to fancybox using their *class*

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    closeBtn: false,
    // hideOnContentClick: true, // this one is for v1.3.x
    closeClick: true,
    padding: 0,
    fitToView: false,
    helpers: {
        overlay: {
            css: {
                background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55)"
            }
        },
        buttons: {}
    }
});
```

Now, if you ALWAYS want to open the first modal after closing the second, you could trigger a `click` to the first link using its `ID` within the `afterClose` callback like :

```
afterClose: function () {
    if (this.element.attr("id") == "fancybox-button3") {
        $("#button2").click();
    }
}
```

**Notice** that we have to validate if the one we are closing is actually the second link before deciding if we want to open the first one again after close.

---

## IMPORTANT!!!!!

There is a **bug** when you open fancybox from within another fancybox with inline content that I documented **[here](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/issues/672)**

As a workaround you can delay the `click` *event* to let clean up fancybox properly before firing it again like:

```
afterClose: function () {
    if (this.element.attr("id") == "fancybox-button3") {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#button2").click();
        }, 200);
    }
}
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/RR9Z4/)**